# Posicionar numero de paginas Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails4

Estou tentando colocar o numero de paginas no roda pe, mas ao dar o crtl+P para imprimir o numero fica logo em baixo do conteudo, que 99% das vezes fica ou na metade da pagina ou um pouco a baixo disso.

Comment: E qual seria a pergunta?

Comment: Como eu posso posicionar a div com o numero da pagina no final dela?

Comment: olá, carlos! por favor inclua o código que gera a página - do jeito que está, a sua pergunta está um pouco difícil de ser respondida! =/ Leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok vou colocar o codigo aqui